# Xamarin not updating bindings when page is in background

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a viewmodel bound to a page. The viewmodel is updating a property reacting to an event. When the page in is in background (covered by other pages) it doesn't update its UI, even when i execute the viewmodel code on UI thread:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
        MyProperty = false;
}
```

Observing this on Android at the moment.
Solved but my own answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If i add a single line to this, it works, the page UI gets updated in background:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async() =>
{
        await Task.Delay(10);
        MyProperty = false;
}
```

Comment: Faced the same problem recently with a multi-language app. The settings page had the same Viewmodel Binding as the Start Page though when changing the language with a Command, the ObservableCollection would be updated but not the Bindings on the Start Page. I tried the OnAppearing Methode, without success. Had to be put it into the constructor and initiate the Start Page from start: App.Current.MainPage = new StartPage(); Did u use Shell?

Comment: yes was using shell with tabs, can be the one to blame in theory too..

Comment: That's quite interesting. I've been wondering whether `BeginInvoke` was sufficient deferral of execution in all cases. You've found a case where it isn't. Important discovery.